# Youtube API v3 youtube.playlistItems().insert() inserts videos in wrong order or misses entries

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, youtube-api, playlist, quota

I wrote a script in python that adds videos to a playlist on youtube via youtube api, text file with video ids and batch system. It works but incorrectly, it appears to me that some videos are being skipped and not added, it picks what to skip at random.

Edit: I run this script about 10 times during testing but in an image attached below theres a new playlist where i ran my program twice hence I painted on it 1st and 2nd.

Thats an example list (numbered for easier reading in this post):

```
videoIds = [ 1'd7ypnPjz81I', 2'vZv9-TWdBJM', 3'FndmvPkI1Ms', 4'q-rXs9Bu6lM', 5'63K5VMx2BZM', 6'9WS6hC-6i68', 7'7uG6E6bVKU0', 8'8EzfBYFU8Q0']
```

Thats a snipped of my code:

```py
   youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)
    batch = youtube.new_batch_http_request()
    for videoId in videoIds:
        batch.add(youtube.playlistItems().insert(
            part="snippet",
            body={
                "snippet": {
                    "playlistId": "my playlist id",
                    "position": 0,
                    "resourceId": {
                        "kind": "youtube#video",
                        "videoId": videoId
                    }
                }
            }
        )
        )
    response = batch.execute()
```

I see only two possible options, first is my batch function messing up, possibly merging two ids together which I think is highly unlikely. Second its failing at youtubes side, either not reading my batch correctly (which i have to admit i have no understanding of beside knowing that it puts small chunks into one single big piece), not catching up on requests resulting in skipping some or something entirely else i have no idea of either. I'm adding an image for clarity.[image: wrong order, missing entries]

EDIT
Also, if i'm allowed to ask, why google quota eats so much of my usage, it counts as 150 or more each time i run my script. Shouldnt batch count only as one interaction costing only 50? And is it possible to skip that usage limit of 10,000 by running script on google site, in some testing window? Im not sure but i think i heard about such trick during my research while writing this program.

**EDIT** I tried adding callback into my script, from what i understand it gives information back that each request has been sent and completed? Anyways it added only three videos at random and since i setted up `callback=main` incorectly it gave me an error:
`TypeError: main() takes 0 positional arguments but 3 were given`
with my poor attempt

```
batch = youtube.new_batch_http_request(callback=main)
```

Number 3 must be the key to it, if only i could somehow extract information about the whole process to see what is actually happening.

**EDIT** I dont understand how to set callback properly https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/docs/batch.md

Comment: Do note that using `new_batch_http_request` does not reduce the amount of quota units the API is accounting for your batched endpoint calls. In this context, the [meaning of batching](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/blob/master/docs/batch.md) is nothing more than: *allow your application to put several API calls into a single HTTP request.*

Answer (score 1):

Following test code snippet inserts videos in correct order, substitute `playlistId` with matching to your setup.

Note: `videoId` '9WS6hC-6i68' is unavailable

Note: Create an empty test playlist to run a test code snippet to verify insertion order

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Sample Python code for youtube.playlistItems.insert
# See instructions for running these code samples locally:
# https://developers.google.com/explorer-help/guides/code_samples#python

import os

import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery
import googleapiclient.errors

scopes = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl"]

def main():
    # Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
    # *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
    os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

    api_service_name = "youtube"
    api_version = "v3"
    client_secrets_file = "client_secret.json"

    playlistId = "your_playlist_id"
    videoIds   = [ 
                   "d7ypnPjz81I",
                   "vZv9-TWdBJM",
                   "FndmvPkI1Ms",
                   "q-rXs9Bu6lM",
                   "63K5VMx2BZM",
                   "7uG6E6bVKU0",
                   "8EzfBYFU8Q0" 
                 ]
    
    # Get credentials and create an API client
    flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
        client_secrets_file, scopes)
    credentials = flow.run_console()
    youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(
        api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

    for videoId in videoIds:
        request = youtube.playlistItems().insert(
            part="snippet",
            body={
              "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
              "snippet": {
                "playlistId": playlistId,
                "position": 0,
                "resourceId": {
                  "kind": "youtube#video",
                  "videoId": videoId
                }
              },
            }
        )
        response = request.execute()

        print(response)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I noticed it being unavailable but it seemed to me that it makes no difference. After testing it without that video in the list in a new playlist problem persists. Any other ideas? I hate being stuck, if i wont be able to work this out i will have to write a code for adding it semi automatically in a browser window.